# Is there a better way of shortening this LINQ statement?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var filteredItemNumber = 0;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
        {
            filteredItemNumber =
                this._objectsRep.Find(
                    r =>
                    r.ObjectTitle.StartsWith(searchTerm) && r.CreatedDate >= timePeriod.Start
                    && r.CreatedDate <= timePeriod.End).Count();
        }
        else
        {
            filteredItemNumber =
                this._objectsRep.Find(t => t.CreatedDate >= timePeriod.Start && t.CreatedDate <= timePeriod.End)
                    .Count();
        }
```

I am sure there must be a shorten way to get rid of the if statement but I cannot figure it out how. when I use the following code the filtering returns different result than what I am expecting. Maybe the parentheses are not in right place ?

```
this._objectsRep.Find(r =>
                searchTerm == null || r.ObjectTitle.StartsWith(searchTerm) && r.CreatedDate >= timePeriod.Start
                && r.CreatedDate <= timePeriod.End).Count()
```

What I am trying to achieve is that if the serchTerm is empty or null just ignore that filter but use the date range only.

Thanks

Comment: `List.Find` is not LINQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need [`List.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which returns a new list, you can use LINQ to count:

```
int filteredItemNumber = _objectsRep.Count(r => 
    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm) || r.ObjectTitle.StartsWith(searchTerm))
    && r.CreatedDate >= timePeriod.Start 
    && r.CreatedDate <= timePeriod.End);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to wrap the searchTerm condition like this:

```
this._objectsRep.Find(r =>
    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm) || r.ObjectTitle.StartsWith(searchTerm)) 
    && r.CreatedDate >= timePeriod.Start
    && r.CreatedDate <= timePeriod.End).Count()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
filteredItemNumber =
                this._objectsRep.Find(
                    r =>
                    r.ObjectTitle.StartsWith(searchTerm??"") && r.CreatedDate >= timePeriod.Start
                    && r.CreatedDate <= timePeriod.End).Count();
```